# OpenCV c++ findHomography not returning same results

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I am stitching three images. Now I wanted to implement warp perspective on the left side (image A and B) and right side (image B an C). I am able to compute both H matrices, but with some wierd behaving.
When I am computing A + B + C. It will do firstly B + C, then A + B. Here the H matric for AB is incorrect, but I dont know why!

When I will do only  A+B then I will recieved "correct values". I tried everything, so I came here. It seems like there is some junk behind after computing B+C, but even I tried .clear() and .release() everything, still same behaving, I also tried to use .clone() everywhere - didnt help. I also checked if correct images are feeded in, yes they are.

I will try to simplify my code as much I can do:

```
    // Stitcher variables
    std::vector<std::pair<Mat, Mat>> images_toCalc;
    std::vector<Mat> images;
    std::vector<Mat> Hs;
    
    //MAIN
    images[2] = imread("E:/JOB/StitchingProject/StitchingApp/x64/Debug/i/left.jpg");
    images[1] = imread("E:/JOB/StitchingProject/StitchingApp/x64/Debug/i/mid.jpg");
    images[0] = imread("E:/JOB/StitchingProject/StitchingApp/x64/Debug/i/right.jpg");
    stitcher->setImages(images, 3);
    stitcher->runStitching2(false);

    // runStitching2
    for (int i = 0; i < this->images.size() - 1; i++) {
        Mat image1 = this->images.at(i).clone();
        Mat image2 = this->images.at(i + 1).clone();
        //if (true) {
        if (!isHalfAlready(i)) {
            flip(image1, image1, 1);
            flip(image2, image2, 1);
            this->images_toCalc.push_back(std::make_pair(image2.clone(), image1.clone()));
        }
        else {
            this->images_toCalc.push_back(std::make_pair(image1.clone(), image2.clone()));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < images_toCalc.size(); i++) {
        Mat H;
        H = this->calcH(images_toCalc.at(i).first, images_toCalc.at(i).second);
        this->Hs.push_back(H);
        H.release();
        if (this->debugLevel[3]) cout << "[" << i << "] H" << endl << Hs.at(i) << endl;
    }
```

Now the buggy part

```
    // this->calcH
    Mat heStitcher::calcH(Mat& image1_toCalc, Mat& image2_toCalc) {
    std::vector< KeyPoint > keypointsObject, keypointsScene;
    Mat descriptorsObject, descriptorsScene;
    Mat image1, image2;
    image1 = image1_toCalc.clone();
    image2 = image2_toCalc.clone();

    if (greyCalc) {
        cv::cvtColor(image1, image1, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::cvtColor(image2, image2, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    }   
    
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create();
    detector->detectAndCompute(image1, Mat(), keypointsObject, descriptorsObject);
    detector->detectAndCompute(image2, Mat(), keypointsScene, descriptorsScene);
    detector->clear();

    vector<std::vector<DMatch>> matches;

    Ptr<FlannBasedMatcher> matcher = cv::FlannBasedMatcher::create();
    matcher->knnMatch(descriptorsObject, descriptorsScene, matches, 2);
    matcher->clear();
    
    double min_dist = 100;
    double max_dist = 0;

    std::vector< DMatch > goodMatches;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
        if (matches[i][0].distance < 0.75f * matches[i][1].distance) {
            goodMatches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }
    
    std::vector< Point2f > obj;
    std::vector< Point2f > scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < goodMatches.size(); i++) {
        obj.push_back(keypointsObject[goodMatches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypointsScene[goodMatches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    cv::Mat H;
    cv::Mat H2;
    if (obj.size() < 4) {
        if (this->debugLevel[2]) cout << endl << "!!!!!! not enough similarities (less than 4) !!!!!!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        H = findHomography(obj, scene, RANSAC);
    }
    image1.release();
    image2.release();
    descriptorsObject.release();
    descriptorsScene.release();
    keypointsObject.clear();
    keypointsScene.clear();
    obj.clear();
    scene.clear();
    goodMatches.clear();
    matches.clear();
    H2 = H.clone();
    H.release();
    return H2;
}
```

After this warpPerspective, border cutting etc, results with matrices in picture 1 a 2. (from where obviously matrices are incorrect). I cannot understant, why when using same script, with same procedure, I am getting different ressults.
[image: When B+C then A+B]
[image: when A+B first]
[image: matches testing]
[image: RIGHT img]
[image: MID img]
[image: LEFT img]

Comment: There is actually a lot going under the hood when you're doing this; so a lot could be going wrong. For example, several steps of the pipeline you are trying to build could be failing. I would recommend inspecting each component of the pipeline individually, starting with the first & simplest steps. First, inspect the SURF features and their respective matches. Are you getting sensible matches? You have very low texture areas throughout. Garbage in -> Garbage out!

Comment: I already debug SURF and matcher. They seems to be correct. The are finding same amoung of keypoints and descriptors. Matches are same, good matches are +2. Not sure how to inspect findHomography pipeline deaply. I´ve added one more image in main post.

Comment: A also did 5 times run to be sure these values are not changing, there are not.

Comment: Are the debug images you just posted with outlier matches pruned? If so, they look terrible, those outliers are enough to throw off any fit. Double check that first. Note there should be a mechanism by which to determine which matches are inliers/outliers post fit (I'm not familiar with opencv but any decent image pipeline should have this.)

Comment: This is what a decent set of matches should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAkbp.jpg

What you have is awful by comparison.

Comment: Yep, I must to agree. Tomorrow I will try to increase distance filtration to have less but more accurate matches.

Comment: can you post all three pictures that you're trying to stitch together?

Comment: I tried to  increase filtration, but it went even worse.@IanChu I attached them to the main post.